# How do I conditionally color the background in a table cell?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am rendering a table with **p:dataTable** (PrimeFaces) and what I want to do is color the background of cells depending on the value of their content.  This is different from coloring a row or a column -- it is the individual cell.

First a CSS problem.  If I do this:

```
                    <p:column headerText="xyzzy">
                        <div style="background-color: green">
                            <h:outputText value="#{rowVar.anumber}" >
                                <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" />
                            </h:outputText>                        
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
```

the background color just of the *content* gets set, not the whole cell.  In other words the padding is still the default.

Second, I want to make the **style** string a variable expression.  I can add a function to the backing bean, but how do I access the table content in the method?   Will this work?

```
<div style="#{bean.computeCSS(rowVar.number}">
```

EDIT:

I figured out a way to do the conditional part, but I still need help with the CSS part.  My solution looks like:

```
                    <p:column headerText="xyzzy">
                        <div class="#{rowVar.anumber gt 0 ? 'colored' : ''}">
                            <h:outputText value="#{rowVar.anumber}">
                                <f:convertNumber groupingUsed="true" />
                            </h:outputText>                        
                        </div>
                    </p:column>
```

Although I dislike getting to fancy in EL, this has the advantage of not needed a backing bean method.

However I still only get the background color set, not the whole cell.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can add a css class to the row and to the column too, that identifies a cell.
Use the dataTable's `rowStyleClass` attribute ([example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/datatableColoring.jsf)).
If you want to color multiple rows:

```
<p:dataTable value="#{bean.rows}" var="rowVar"
     rowStyleClass="#{rowVar.firstCol gt 0 ? 'firstColColored' : ''}
                           #{rowVar.secondCol gt 0 ? 'secondColColored' : ''}">
     <p:column styleClass="firstCol">...
     <p:column styleClass="secondCol">
```

css:

```
.firstColColored .firstCol {
     background: pink;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

how about adding padding to your class , with px or percents...

something like this

```
.colored{
    background-color:yellow;
    padding-top:25px;
    padding-bottom:25px;
    padding-right:50px;
    padding-left:50px;
}
```