# set background colour for cells on dynamic created columns with primefaces datatable

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

i create dynamic columns with this model, found as example for dynamic colums (but no documentation):

```
static public class ColumnModel implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String header;
    private String property;

    public ColumnModel(String header, String property) {
        this.header = header;
        this.property = property;
    }

    public String getHeader() {
        return header;
    }

    public String getProperty() {
        return property;
    }
}
```

[image: xhtml-site]

Works fine, but now i want to change the background colour of some cells depending on its value. How can I implement this? Any hints? More Information needed?

Comment: can help this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9656774/how-do-i-conditionally-color-the-background-in-a-table-cell

Comment: The link @Guillermo81 poste indeed helps, but instead of putting the EL on the div inside the column(s), put it on the stylyeClass on the column(s)

Comment: the links are helpfull, thank you.